# Prove that $z_n\rightarrow z=r(\cos(A)+i\sin(A))$ iff $r_n\rightarrow r$ and $A_n\rightarrow A$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$z_n=r_n(\cos(A_n)+i\sin(A_n))$ and $z=r(\cos(A)+i\sin(A))$

Prove that $z_n\rightarrow z=r(\cos(A)+i\sin(A))$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

if and only if 
$r_n\rightarrow r$ and $A_n\rightarrow A$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Note: $A_n$ is a principle argument and $0<A\le2\pi$

This is a question I just thought of myself. I was trying to use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition of the limit but was hard to do.

Comment: what if we make it like mod 2pi

Comment: Still more caution is needed: try $r_n=1/n$ and $A_n=n$.